# Get Correct Latitude and Longitude using accuracy in React-native

Tags: google-maps, react-native, google-maps-markers

I am working on navigation app using react-native

My Problem is GPS give Coordinates And draw the marker on map but 
marker always keep distance from Road

Where i am wrong

Image in Link

[Ride Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzrlJ.png)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think this would be helpful

```
geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geo_success, [geo_error], 
{
enableHighAccuracy: true,
});
```

Comment: its increase accuracy. [check here ](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.59/geolocation#getcurrentposition)

Comment: I was just trying to point out that your answer could be better presented. "Use this" with just a piece of code isn't really a good quality answer...

Comment: GPS accuracy is also vary in mobile sets . try to run it on different mobile or ios

Comment: Test in 18 Mobile sets